# How to simplify following the boolean expression $A+\bar{A} B \bar{C}$

Tags: boolean-algebra

Equation to minimize using Boolean Algebra Laws:
$A+\bar{A} B \bar{C}$

I have tried doing this but i am unsure of the answer:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\text { Let } K=B \bar{C} \\
A+\bar{A} K=A+K=A+B \bar{C}
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always add a lesser expression as in

$$
    A = A + AX
$$
Therefore

\begin{align}
  A + \bar{A}B\bar{C} & = (A + AB\bar{C}) + \bar{A}B\bar{C} \\
                      & = A + (AB\bar{C} + \bar{A}B\bar{C}) \\
                      & = A + (A+\bar{A})B\bar{C} \\
                      & = A + B\bar{C}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

One more possible way
$$A+\overline{A}B\overline{C} =A+B\overline{A+C}=A+ \overline{\overline{B}+A+C}=\\
=\overline{\overline{A}(\overline{B}+A+C)} = \overline{\overline{A}(\overline{B}+C)}=A+B\overline{C}$$